# c++ pointer scope

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

What happens when you have the following code:

```
void makeItHappen()
{
    char* text = "Hello, world";
}
```

Does `text` go out of scope and get deleted automatically or does it stay in the memory?

And what about the following example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
      SomeClass();
      ~SomeClass();
};

SomeClass::SomeClass() { }
SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
    std::cout << "Destroyed?" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass* someClass = new SomeClass();
    return 0;
} // What happend to someClass?
```

Does the same thing occur here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
 char* text = "Hello, world";
```

Here an automatic variable (a pointer) is created on the stack and set to point to a value in **constant memory**, which means:

- the string literal in `""` exists through the whole program execution.
- you are not responsible for "allocating" or "freeing" it
- you may not change it. If you want to change it, then you have to allocate some "non-constant memory" and copy it there.

When the pointer goes out of scope, the memory pointer itself (4 bytes) is freed, and the string is still in the same place - constant memory.

For the latter:

```
SomeClass* someClass = new SomeClass();
```

Then `someClass` pointer will also be freed when it goes out of scope (since the pointer itself is on the stack too, just in the first example)... **but not the object!**

The keyword `new` basically means that you allocate some memory for the object on **free store** - and you're responsible for calling `delete` sometime in order to release that memory.

Comment: @Kos: Does this mean, the number 2 in `int x = 2;` also exists through the whole program execution?

Comment: The difference is that the number 2 doesn't need to have an address in the memory, and the string does (as it's being pointed to by the pointer). *(This number 2 exists somethere out there in the code section of your memory, which you don't ever need to access directly, because it's, well, the code, not the data.)*

Comment: @Kos Thanks for a great answer! But, what's the point of keeping `"Hello, world"` in memory?

Comment: You need to keep it *somewhere*, right? :) It needs to be in the memory so that you'll be able to pass its address to, say, the `printf` function.

Comment: @Kos Maybe I didn't ask my question properly, I meant something along the lines of; does it stay in memory till the end of the method or till the end of execution? Sorry (:

Comment: @Kos: So the array in `int x[3] = {1,2,3};` ,like the string, lies in constant memory right?

Comment: @sad_man, I'm not sure whether the initial values of the initializer `{1,2,3}` would land in data part (like strings) or in the code part (you can use `g++ -S` and examine the assembler output for that :)), but the array itself, `int x[3]`, lands as 3*4 bytes on the stack, so in normal read/write memory, as one may expect. Note here how `const char* c = "hello"` and `"char c[] = "hello"` are totally different.

Comment: @Kevin, the whole code of your program (the compiled binary code) stays in the memory during the program execution, and the constant string literals obey the same rules here.

Answer (score 13):

> Does `text` go out of scope

Yes! It is local to the function `makeItHappen()` and when the function returns it goes out of scope. However the pointed to string literal `"Hello, world";` has static storage duration and is stored in read only section of the memory.

> And what about the following example:
>
> ......
> Does the same thing occur here?

Your second code sample leaks memory.

`SomeClass* someClass = new SomeClass();`

`someClass` is local to `main()` so when main returns it being an automatic variable gets destroyed. However the pointed to object remains in memory and there's no way to free it after the function returns. You need to explicitly write `delete someClass` to properly deallocate the memory.

Comment: +1 "the pointed to string literal "Hello, world"; has static storage duration"

Comment: Leaks memory because you haven't deleted the object you created.

Answer (score 8):

The variable text does go out of scope (however the string literal is not deleted).

For objects that you allocate with new (like your SomeClass), you need to explicitly delete them. If you want objects allocated like this to be automatically deleted, take a look at [boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) (std::unique_ptr if your compiler is c++0x aware).

This will automatically delete the allocated object when the shared pointer goes out of scope.

Your code would then look like this:

```
int main(int argv, char **argv)
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<SomeClass> ptr(new SomeClass);
  // the object is automatically deleted
  return 0;
}
```

Note: In this particular example, you could also use std::auto_ptr (but this will be deprecated in c++0x).

Note 2: As was pointed out in the comments by Kos, it is in this case more appropriate to use boost::scoped_ptr or std::unique_ptr (c++0x). My answer first used boost::shared_ptr, which is more appropriate if you need to share ownership of a pointer between several classes for instance.

Comment: I'd +1... but then I noticed that you mentioned the reference-counting pointers, when the more appropriate tool is `std::unique_ptr` from c++0x / `boost::scoped_ptr` / `std::auto_ptr`. Those are responsible for deleting the object when the pointer goes out of scope - and exactly for that.

Comment: @Kos: You are absolutely correct that in this particular case unique_ptr is more appropriate. I'll make a change...

Comment: +1 then. :) (is that last shared_ptr link left intentionally?)

Comment: Ahh you have a good eye... :) I changed the link text to be more accurate. Maybe I can hire you for rep to proofread all my answers... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the string literal is stored in data segment of your executable.
In the second case you do not have to call `delete` (in your example program just terminates)   since on program termination the heap is freed anyway for the process.
Note though that there are OS (as I have read) that you have to explicitly release heap even if the program terminates since it will not be cleaned up at termination for you.
Of course programmer is responsible for memory management in C++ and objects you create on heap should be `delete`ed once unneeded.